# How to map Sonar rule set to equivalent Parasoft rule set?

Tags: rule, sonarqube

I used to use the following Parasoft rule sets for SCA:

JTest Rule ID and Rule Description:

BD.PB.ARRAY-1 (Avoid accessing arrays out of bounds)

BD.EXCEPT.NP-1 (Avoid Null Pointer Exception)

CDD.DUPC-2 (Avoid code duplication)

MOBILE.J2ME.OOME-3 (Catch 'OutOfMemoryError' for large array allocations)

BD.RES.LEAKS-1 (Ensure resources are deallocated)

BD.PB.ZERO-1 (Avoid division by zero)

UC.UPC-2 (Avoid unused "private" classes or interfaces)

UC.DEAD-1 (Avoid dead stores (variable never used)

OPT.CEL-3 (Do not call methods in loop condition statements)

BD.PB.DEREF-2 (Avoid dereferencing before checking for null)

DotTest ID and Rule Description:

OOM.CYCLO - 2 (Follow the limit for Cyclomatic Complexity)

METRICS.CBO-1 (Follow the limit for Coupling between objects)

METRICS.MI-1 (Follow the limit for Maintainability Index (70))

CS.EXCEPT.RETHROW – 2 (Avoid clearing stack trace while rethrowing exceptions)

IFD.SRII – 4 (Implement IDisposable in types which are using system resources)

IFD.SRIF - 1 (Provide finalizers in types which use resources)

CS.CDD.DUPC – 2 (Avoid code duplication)

CS.CDD.DUPM-2 (Avoid method duplication)

OPU.IGHWE – 1 (Override the GetHashCode method whenever you override the Equals method)

Now I am looking for if SonarQube rule set include the above Parasoft rule set or not. But it is hard for me to tell which one in SonarQube rule sets is equivalent to the above Parasoft rule sets. Does anyone know?

Thanks

June

Comment: Parasoft BD.* rules are flow-analysis based which allows them to find more complex violations (even in inter-methods and inter-module cases), you will not find such rules in Sonarqube.